# Preventing duplicate XMLHttpRequests in Django

Tags: django, concurrency, locking

In my app, clicking a button sends a XHR request to my server to upgrade an account and charge the user.

```
def upgradeView(request):
    if request.user.upgraded == False:
         billAccount(request.user.id)
    else: 
         return HttpRequests('Already billed')
    request.user.upgraded = True
    request.user.save()
    return HttpResponse('OK!')
```

I can alter the button using Javascript so that it will be disabled after the user clicks it once. How can I confirm on the server side that the user can't submit 5 XHR requests simultaneously and end up getting billed 5 times? I have a manual check, checking whether they have already been billed, but what if the billAccount function takes a few seconds, and multiple requests are able to trigger the `billAccount` call before the user is able to be set as upgraded?

The more I think about it, the more it seems impossible prevent multiple requests sliding in. Even if the `billAccount` call is a milisecond, that's still enough time for multiple requests to come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using `select_for_update` and `transaction.atomic()` for pessimistic locking, and the "no_wait" argument. What this does is prevent any other process from selecting that object as it is locked. [Here's](https://hakibenita.com/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models) a great resource that goes further in depth.

Here is how I believe you could lock the row so that multiple transactions couldn't happen simultaniously:

```
def upgradeView(request):
    with transaction.atomic():
        u = Users.objects.select_for_update(nowait=True).filter(pk=request.user.pk)
        if u.upgraded == False:
             billAccount(u.id)
        else: 
             return HttpRequests('Already billed')
        u.upgraded = True
        u.save()
        return HttpResponse('OK!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another attribute that will be set to True when a request sent and then back to False before response sent.
And depending on the value of that attribute you decide whether to make bill request or not.

```
def upgradeView(request):
   if request.user.bill_state == 'open':
      # So there is a biliing request is running and we
   else:
      # set bill state to true to prevent any further requests
      request.user.bill_state = 'open'
      request.user.save()

   # make normal process of billing here an before end the request
   request.user.bill_state = 'close'
   request.user.save()
```

i think change a variable from 'open' to 'close' will be faster than billing and you can prevent multiple requests.